# Visual Studio Project Template for a Browser-based Desktop Application

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, browser-based

I am starting the development of a **browser-based** desktop application (HTML + JavaScript) with **no web server involved**. It will be a single static HTML file using `FileApi` for its input and BlobUrls for output.

I consider using Visual Studio Community as the IDE for that development, but I can’t find the right project template to use.

My wish-list is:

- Support for basic front-end languages: JavaScript, HTML, CSS.
- Refactoring tools spanning several languages and files
  (like renaming a JavaScript object or a `class` attribute).
- JavaScript debugging within the IDE, with connection to several
  browsers.
- No server (not even `localhost`) required.
- Support for
  JavaScript build tools (bundle, minify, … but no
  transpiler)
- Git Support.

Is this available?

Comment: Visual Studio has support for this but only when using TypeScript it seems.  I've struggled with the same problem a long time ago.  I would recommend just switching over to Visual Studio Code, which provides everything on your wish-list and has a lot more customization than Visual Studio Community.  https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: @ToastyMallows: Thanks for your advices. (I didn't even heard of Visual Studio Code). Since your are answering my question, please consider publish your comment as a regular answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has support for this but only when using TypeScript it seems. I've struggled with the same problem a long time ago.  What I did was create an ASP.NET application but then I didn't use any Web Forms pages, I just used normal HTML pages and JavaScript.

I would recommend just switching over to Visual Studio Code, which provides everything on your wish-list and has a lot more customization than Visual Studio Community.

http://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: After a few hours experimenting with VS Code I can confirm it is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Excellent!  VSCode seems to get quicker updates as well, and it's open source!